# Singleton on the Simulator vs singleton on a real device?

Tags: ios, singleton, ios-simulator

I am using a singleton for some shared stuff. In the simulator, the app crashes ocasionally. Tracking the crash down shows that the the properties of my singleton became dealocated. Those crashes never happend on a real device. Does the simulator handle memory managemend different? GC maybe?

Changed the singleton to match [this pattern](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/). The Simulator dont crash now, but I am not sure about the memory handling on the real device. I assume that this solution will cause problems.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably had the singleton wrong in the first attempt. Memory management on the Simulator works the same way as on the device, at least in principle. In practice there are some differences because of timing issues or because the Simulator has plenty memory and will not send you the memory warnings. But these differences will not affect a correctly written singleton.

The linked singleton code looks good on a skim. In my opinion you would do best to [get rid of the singletons completely](http://zmotula.tumblr.com/post/1390385240/why-singletons-suck) and wire your application using Interface Builder or dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks. Even the singelton is fine and crashes apeared to have gone, he still seems to dealocate properties. The properties that cause problems are pointer to objects. Getting them works, changing them lead ocasional to a crash in the simulator. Seems I oversee something fundametal again.:/

Comment: Show us a [short sample](http://sscce.org/) of the code that doesn’t work. It’s quite possible that you have the properties of the singleton class wrong.